# How to get status when add new comment using json api in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, json, wordpress

i am new to Android Studio and making app using WordPress Website as backend , i want users ti post comment on posts which is working well but i want to tell users if their comment has been submitted successfully or got any error.. this is my code

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://www.sikhnama.com/?json=respond/submit_comment&post_id=" + Postid
                            + "&name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&content=" + comment)
                    .build();
              try {
                Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello Javatpoint",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Comment", "Comment Failed");
            }
```

i have log "comment failed" but it never comes even if failed comment.. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/3.3.1/okhttp3/Call.html#execute--) for `OkHttpClient`. Execution of the call will not throw an exception in case of an http error response code (and it would be a very bad library design if it did so), only on network failure, interruption etc.

You can check the `reponse.isSuccessful()` and log your "comment failed" message or whatever.

Comment: i have tried it but still its success even have error on comment

Comment: what is the `response.code()` and the response body in case of a failure?

Comment: I have treid this if(response.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"REsponse succesfull",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"REsponse Not succesfull",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

Comment: and the response is always successfull

Comment: ok i got error in response.body() , thanks